# Hive CREATE TABLE takes long time to run and does not complete in Cloudera

Tags: hive, cloudera, sqoop, impala

HIVE CREATE TABLE not working in CLOUDERA 5.8


`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS retail_db.products (product_id   INT,product_category_id INT ,product_name  STRING, product_description STRING ,product_price  DECIMAL, product_image   STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/cloudera/retail_db/products'`

Takes lot of time and never completes executing.

Also *Sqoop Hive import* is not completing.

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --target-dir /user/cloudera/retail_db/products_test --table products --hive-import  --create-hive-table  --hive-table retail_db.products`

The script stops at:

 Log:

```
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=0
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=173993
17/07/03 06:31:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 169.915 KB    in 2,340.3572 seconds (74.3446 bytes/sec)
17/07/03 06:31:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1345 records.
17/07/03 06:31:48 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `products` AS t LIMIT 1
17/07/03 06:31:49 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.8.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties`
```

Tried restarting the hive-services.

But the CREATE TABLE tablename works in Impala.

Comment: Mention the configuration details .Does the tool hang? Or some warning/error message is thrown?

Comment: 5.10 also similar issues, not easy to see why